# Obtener la linea y columna de un nodo XML

Tags: python, xml

En ese proyecto estoy definiendo configuraciones de objetos en en formato XML. Un ejemplo es este es el caso de un menu contextual:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <menu name="remates" widget="uiRemates" onshow="showMenu" >
        <action name="add" target="add" title="Nuevo Remate" icon=":/crud/add" disabled="" shortcut="CTRL+Key_A" />
        <action name="remove" target="remove" title="Eliminar Remate" icon=":/crud/delete" disabled="" />
        <action name="remove_apuesta" target="removeApuesta" title="Eliminar Apuesta" icon=":/crud/delete" disabled="" />
        <action name="print_remate" target="printRemate" disabled="" title="Imprimir Remate" />
    </menu>
</root>
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es recuperar esa configuración con Python y como ven en el source [[código completo]](https://bitbucket.org/ricardosiri68/mchoof/src/5c9f012ca77c5185feb41f21b97577fc527ddda0/config/table_model.py?at=develop&fileviewer=file-view-default#table_model.py-107)

```
def configField(self, field_element):
    name = field_element.getAttribute('name')
    if not name:
        raise ModelConfigFieldnameError(
            self.model,
            field_element
        )

    if not name in self.model.field_keys:
        raise ModelConfigNotHasFieldError(
            self.model,
            name,
            field_element
        )

    index_column = self.model.field_keys.index(name)
    self.setHeader(field_element, index_column)
```

`field_element` es un objeto de tipo `<class xml.dom.minidom.Element ..>`

Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo determinar en que línea y columna se encuentra ese elemento? Para así mejorar el detalle de mis excepciones cuando una configuracion XML esté mal.

Comment: Aquí está la respuesta (en SO en inglés) http://stackoverflow.com/a/28677845/142904

Comment: @KristianDamian Fijate que no se trata de una subclase de ConfigParser

Comment: Parece que es imposible obtener esta información en los objetos ordinales de tipo `minidom.Element`, se ha perdido. Pero tienes dos opciónes: [añadirla en los objetos durante el análisis como describido aquí](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789171/python-reporting-line-column-of-origin-of-xml-node/5133181#5133181) (inglés SO) o usar un otro analizador, ej. [lxml](http://lxml.de/parsing.html) que provee `sourceline` atributo a todos los elementos (ni columnas, ni propiedades para los atributos, lo siento)

Comment: @RicharSiri lo que usted pregunta no tiene mucho sentido, ya que los xml se basan en la estructura de arbol , por lo que no tiene sentido aplicar una estructura vectorial /matricial como la que usted plantea.

Comment: Creo que según las reglas si pones una respuesta de Stack en Inglés debes ponerla en español, como respuesta, y adjuntar el enlace como referencia.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilzar [lxml](http://lxml.de/) para realizarlo. Esta librería te da más información por cada elemento del `xml` y entre ellos un campo llamado `sourceline` que es exactamente el que necesitas.

Destacar que esta librería sólo es compatible con python 2 (no con el 3) pero ya entra dentro de la definición de tu proyecto.

Para ser aún más específico, dado tu `xml` en `root` se puede:

```
print root.find('remove').sourceline
```

Y en tu caso eso devovlería `3`.

Más información sobre `sourceline` en la documentación del [elemento en lxml](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html).

He encontrado también [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538248/any-one-have-an-example-that-uses-the-element-sourceline-method-from-lxml-html) (con respuesta) en SO en inglés dónde piden información específica del `sourceline` por si te hiciera falta al aplicarlo.